# BPEL output strings

Tags: web-services, eclipse-plugin, bpel

I am new to BPEL and web services.
I have a webservice returning an array of strings. In BPEL I invoke this webservice and deploy the webservice in Apache ODE.
I am using the BPEL designer tool in Eclipse.

The result I get from the BPEL service is the first element in the array, in the console I can see that the whole array is being passed. How can I set the output as array? The type of my output variable is String, I can not find a type such as list, array or list of strings.

This list of strings:

```
<xs:element name="getAvailableBungalowsResponse">
            <xs:complexType>
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="return" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
```

should go in this one:

```
<complexType name="Bungalow">

            <sequence maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
                <element name="bungalowInfo" type="string"></element>
            </sequence>
        </complexType>
```

Bpel from-to looks like this:

```
<bpel:copy>
            <bpel:from part="parameters" variable="HolidayVillageServiceLinkResponse">
            </bpel:from>
            <bpel:to part="bungalows" variable="output">
            </bpel:to>
        </bpel:copy>
```

Error I get in the BPEL designer is the following:

```
The from-spec of "<xs:complexType>" is not compatible with to-spec of "<complexType "Bungalow">" - Element <ns:return> in platform:/resource/HolidayVillage/bpelContent/HollidayVillage.wsdl differs from <tns:bungalowInfo> in platform:/resource/HolidayVillage/bpelContent/HolidayVillageReservationArtifacts.wsdl - different QNames: ns:return vs tns:bungalowInfo HolidayVillageReservation.bpel  /HolidayVillage/bpelContent line 98 BPEL Validation Marker
```

Answer (score 2):

Types in BPEL are defined in terms of XMLSchema, thus there is no concept like an array or list but you can define a sequence of string elements by setting the cardinality to unbounded. If you need to assemble a list of strings for the return value, please also see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14129798/returning-complex-type-response-at-bpel)

Comment: ok, thanks. The invoked service returns a sequence of strings. I made a complex type with a sequence of strings in BPEL. I get an error: from-spec is not compatible with to-spec.
I editted the question above with more info